# Using goutte to read from a file / string

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, goutte

I'm using Goutte to make a webscraper.

For development, I've saved a .html document I'd like to traverse (so i'm not constantly making requests to the website). Here's what I have so far:

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$html=file_get_contents('test.html');
$crawler = $client->request(null,null,[],[],[],$html);
```

Which based of what I know should call request in Symfony\Component\BrowserKit, and pass in the raw body data. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException' with message 'cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\Users\Ally\Sites\scrape\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.
```

If I were to just use DomCrawler, it's non-trivial to create a crawler using a string. (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html). I'm just unsure about how to do the equivalent with Goutte.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-trival to create a crawler using a string"? What's wrong with new Crawler(file_get_contents('test.html')) ?

Comment: I wont be able to use all the Goutte methods like 
$crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Sign in')->link());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools you decided to use make real http connections and are not suitable for what you want to do. At least out of the box.

**Option 1: Implement your own BrowserKit Client**

All goutte does is it extends BrowserKit's [Client](https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit/blob/master/Client.php). It implements http requests with Guzzle.

All you need to do to implement your own client, is to extend the `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client` and provide the [`doRequest()` method](https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit/blob/292751e7b351b1e7d400c7529c07d713af2ff92a/Client.php#L371-L378):

```php
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;

class FilesystemClient extends Client
{
    /**
     * @param object $request An origin request instance
     *
     * @return object An origin response instance
     */
    protected function doRequest($request)
    {
        $file = $this->getFilePath($request->getUri());

        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            return new Response('Page not found', 404, []);
        }

        $content = file_get_contents($file);

        return new Response($content, 200, []);
    }

    private function getFilePath($uri)
    {
        // convert an uri to a file path to your saved response
        // could be something like this:
        return preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z_\-\.]#', '_', $uri).'.html';
    }
}
```

```php
 $client = new FilesystemClient();
 $client->request('GET', '/test');
```

Client's `request()` needs to accept real URIs, therefore you need to implement your own logic to convert it to a filesystem location.

Have a look at [Goutte's Client](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/blob/228173540a2c7ef25e06f81c5d8b9883ed15e7d4/Goutte/Client.php#L78) for insipration.

**Option 2: Implement a custom Guzzle handler**

Since Goutte uses Guzzle, you could provide your own Guzzle handler that would load responses from files, instead of making real http requests. Have a look at the [handlers and middleware doc](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html#handlers).

If you're just after caching responses so you make less http requests, Guzzle provides support for this already.

**Option 3: Use DomCrawler directly**

```php
new Crawler(file_get_contents('test.html'))
```

The only drawback is you'll loose some of convenience methods of the BrowserKit client, like `click()` or `selectLink()`.